# Is there a way to nest an "if" statement in a "for" loop, to then return as "True", "False", or "Unsure" in a new list?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I currently have a Series column ("DateDiff") in a DataFrame, and I am trying to create a new list/series next to it that returns "True", "False", or "Unsure" based on the values in the "DateDiff" column.

I've tried to create a nested if function inside a for loop, and then append these returns into a new list named "fraud".

```
minus = condensed['DEATHDATE'] - condensed['STOP']
minus = minus.tolist()
fraud = []
for value in minus:
    if value in minus > 0:
        fraud.append('True')
    elif value in minus < 0:
        fraud.append('False')
    elif value in minus == 0:
        fraud.append('Unsure')
```

I'm expecting it to run through each line of [minus], check to see if it is >, <, or == to 0, and then return and append "True", "False", or "Unsure" to the list [list].

Whenever I try to run the code above, I keep getting this error message.

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Because, `minus` is list and 0 is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already looping through the list, you should be using the variable `value` to refer to the current item in the iteration. Hence, your if statement should look like this instead:

```
if value > 0:
```

Same for the others. Basically, you need to remove the `in minus` on each line, otherwise its comparing the whole `minus` list with the number 0, which is not what you want happening.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using a for loop, you don't need to say `if value in minus > 0`.  Minus is a list and you cannot compare lists to integers.  Instead all you need is `if value > 0` since it is already inside the for loop.  Your code should look like the following:

```
minus = condensed['DEATHDATE'] - condensed['STOP']
minus = minus.tolist()
fraud = []
for value in minus:
    if value > 0:
        fraud.append('True')
    elif value < 0:
        fraud.append('False')
    elif value == 0:
        fraud.append('Unsure')
```

Just a simple misunderstanding in your for loop.  Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you also for this! Helped clarify to me for later use.